# Sentry - React - capture errors iframe and only iframe

Tags: reactjs, sentry

**Context**
We're developing a React-based app that is being used as a 'widget' on other websites. Our entire react app is wrapped in an iframe using [react-frame-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-frame-component).

For developing purposes, we use [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) to log any errors ([@sentry/browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/browser) sdk).

**Problem**
We noticed that once our app is integrated on any website errors don't get logged to Sentry anymore and we're not entirely sure how to solve this.

So we're seeking a solution to log errors to Sentry that occur inside an iframe and ONLY inside that iframe.

Is it possible to somehow tell Sentry what window/target/scope to use?

Using [React Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) might be an option to consider. However, it doesn't capture all errors.

**Iframe - code**

```
...
render(
    <Iframe initialContent={initialIframeContent}>
        <App />
    </Iframe>,
    document.getElementById(containerId)
);
...
```

**Sentry integration  - code**

```
...
Sentry.init({
    environment: env,
    dsn: SENTRY_DSN
});
...
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I have a very similar situation

Comment: @NicholasHaley sorry for the late reply. I just added our solution as an answer

Answer (score 4):

We couldn't find a direct solution so we ended up using React Error Boundaries to capture any crash and log it to sentry.

Keep in mind that Error Boundaries doesn't capture all crashes (see quote below). So we came up with a hook that would make Error Boundaries capture those crashes as well (except for the server side rendering and crashes inside Error Boundaries itself).

See [inspiration hook](https://medium.com/trabe/catching-asynchronous-errors-in-react-using-error-boundaries-5e8a5fd7b971).

> **Note**
>
> Error boundaries do not catch errors for:
>
> - Event handlers (learn more)
> - Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or
>     requestAnimationFrame callbacks)
> - Server side rendering
> - Errors thrown in the error boundary itself (rather than its children)

~ [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

**ErrorBoundary.js**

```
const initialState = {
    hasError: false,
    showError: false
};

export default class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
    };

    static getDerivedStateFromError () {
        return { hasError: true };
    }

    state = initialState;

    componentDidCatch (error) {
        logToSentry(error);
    };
    ...
```

See [sentry docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/react/)

**useError.js**

```
const useError = () => {
    const [_, setError] = useState();

    return useCallback(
        e => {
            setError(() => {
                throw e;
            });
        },
        [setError],
    );
};

export default useError;
```

**Usage sample**

```
const throwError = useError();

const someAsyncFn = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await asyncApiRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        throwError(e)
    }
}, []);

const someEventHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        doSomethingThatMightCrash();
    } catch (e) {
        throwError(e)
    }
}, []);
```

It's a bit tedious and there might be ways to simplify this even more but it does its job.